# Express doesn't get another user with .map()

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose-schema

I came to a problem, where I can create conversations with multiple people 2 and so on. However, I can't understand why it doesn't store data to seperate User models.

Here is a code that you only need to know:

```
router.post(
  "/",
  auth,
  [
    check("conversators", "There should be at least two conversators").isLength(
      { min: 2 }
    ),
  ],
  async (req, res) => {
    const { conversators } = req.body;
    const errors = validationResult(req);

    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
      return res.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array() });
    }

    try {
      let conversation = new Conversation({
        user: req.user.id,
        conversators: conversators,
      });

      await conversators.map(async (conversator) => {
        let user = await User.findById(conversator);
        let newData = user;
        newData.conversations.push(conversation.id);

        console.log('Created data', newData);

        let newUser = await User.findOneAndUpdate(
          { user: conversator },
          {
            $set: {
              newData,
            },
          },
          { new: true }
        );

        await newUser.save();
        console.log(newUser);
      });

      await conversation.save();
      res.status(200).json(conversation);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error.message);
      res.status(500).send("Server error.");
    }
  }
);

module.exports = router;
```

What I can assure is that this line: `console.log('Created data', newData);` prints the desired data. However, the next console: `console.log(newUser);` prints the same User model as the previous one.

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const UserSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  surname: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  conversations: [
    {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "conversation",
    },
  ],
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
});

module.exports = User = mongoose.model("user", UserSchema);
```

Comment: Remember that arrow functions only return _without_ a function block. If you use `(...) => { ... }` you need to explicitly return something, so you'll want to fix the function you passed into `conversators.map()`. And you'll also want to await `Promise.all(conservators...)`, because right now you're awaiting "an array", which won't do much (even if it's an array of promises; `await` only works when followed by a promise).

Comment: I would advise to tell something about the fields of `User` model you use here. At least those, used in this code block.

Comment: Added User model

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Hey! It actually worked! I created a new Promise which only resolves when the user is updated. That's it :D

Answer (score 0):

The reason might be the difference in search methods used to get a record for `newData` and `newUser`. You have used `User.findById` for `newData`, which will obviously return different objects for different ids. But `User.findOneAndUpdate` uses filter criteria that may satisfy several results, but only first will be returned. So it boldly depends on what that `user` field is.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the part that I changed and started to see the data on MongoDB:

```
await conversators.map(async (conversator) => {
  let user = await User.findById(conversator);
  let newData = user;
  newData.conversations.push(conversation.id);
  
  new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    user = await User.findOneAndUpdate(
      { id: conversator },
      {
        $set: {
          newData,
        },
      },
      { new: true }
    );
    return resolve;
  })

  return await user.save();
});
```

<sub>*Posted on behalf of the question asker*</sub>